# How do you import android modules on android?

Tags: android, python, python-import

I'm running Python3 on Android and I can import android, but I can't import any android submodules.

My goal is to have my scripts react to events, such as plugging/unplugging the headset, but I'm struggling to follow the examples found online.

One group seems to think that you should import jnius and use this autoclass() helper, while the other things you should directly import android.broadcast.

I'm struggling because python cannot find either jnius or android.broadcast installed, yet android.Android() works fine.

How do you properly import the android.broadcast.BroadcastListener object in python?

Comment: `from android.broadcast import BroadcastReceiver` does not work?

Comment: I can run the python3 interpreter in console mode on my phone:
>>> from android.broadcast import BroadcastReceiver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named broadcast **EDITING FLAGS NOT BEING RESPECTED, SORRY**

Comment: I've tried uninstalling everything except QPython3 (has SL4A built in) and I still cannot import any android submodules. I tried with installing SL4A on top as well, and get the same error.

Comment: What did you do to cause broadcast to exist on your system? What was installed to make it appear? I feel like I've installed and uninstalled everything in every possible order...

Comment: Can you show me which guides or tutorials are you following?

Comment: These docs reflect the examples I've found of Android event handling in python: http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#module-android.broadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import `android.broadcast` because the module doesn't exits. I've unzipped `/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/python32.zip` and there is no trace of broadcasts. If you can find the module, you can put it under `/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages`.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm able to shed some light on my problem. Apparently Py4A, QPython3, and **Kivy** all call their projects 'Python for Android' and the documentation I was looking at was for Kivy (had no idea until I clicked 'Edit on Github' and the light dawned).